# if (input == operator): not working in python calculator?

Tags: python, math, calculator

```
print ("THE CALCULATOR")

print ("Type 1st no")

n = input()

print("Type 2nd no")

n2 = input()

print("Which Operator?")

n3 = input()

if (n3 == +):

    print("The anwser is", int(n) + int(n2))
```

Comment: edit question and use special functions to format code - `Ctrl+K` or ```

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: image shows only warning from IDE. Did you try to run it ? Did you get error message? aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: ok, @furas I will remember this next time. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change:-**

```py
if (n3 == +):
```

**To:-**

```
if (n3 == '+'):
```